# JAVASCRIPT Search in 3D array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array with some data like this :

```js
const
  data = [
    {"key":9054,"title":"1","children":[
      {"key":8959,"title":"1-0","idFather":8959,"tableIsFamily":false,"children":[]},
      {"key":8943,"title":"1-1","idFather":8943,"tableIsFamily":false,"children":[]},
      {"key":9021,"title":"1-2","idFather":9021,"tableIsFamily":false,"children":[]},
      {"key":8969,"title":"1-3","idFather":8969,"tableIsFamily":false,"children":[]}]},
      {"key":9040,"title":"2","children":[
        {"key":8957,"title":"2-0","idFather":8957,"tableIsFamily":false,"children":[]},   
        {"key":8941,"title":"2-1","idFather":8941,"tableIsFamily":false,"children":[
          {"key":8947,"title":"2-1-0","idFather":8941},
          {"key":9855,"title":"2-1-1","idFather":8941}
        ]},
        {"key":8949,"title":"3-0","idFather":8949,"tableIsFamily":false,"children":[]},
        {"key":8983,"title":"3-1","idFather":8983,"tableIsFamily":false,"children":[]},
        {"key":10070,"title":"3-2","idFather":10070,"tableIsFamily":false,"children":[]}
      ]}
    ];
```

And I have another array with some Id's like this :

```js
[9054, 9021, 9040, 8941, 8947]
```

I want to filter the data array and get only matched array with the second array, I have tried some map/filter but it seem to be more difficult thann i think, Have you any ideas how to deal with this array please ?

The expected output should be :

```js
const
  data = [
    {"key":9054,"title":"1","children":[
      {"key":9021,"title":"1-2","idFather":9021,"tableIsFamily":false,"children":[]},
      {"key":9040,"title":"2","children":[  
        {"key":8941,"title":"2-1","idFather":8941,"tableIsFamily":false,"children":[
          {"key":8947,"title":"2-1-0","idFather":8941},
        ]},
      ]}
    ];
```

Thank you!

Comment: Hi, can you post an example of the expected output?

Comment: Hi, done! :) please take a look in the edited post :)

Comment: You asked this question 4 hours ago, rather than reposting the same question you should edit your original question so that it gets the answers you need – clarify any details asked for in the comments, and **show what you have tried**. see [How do I get attention for one of my own questions without a good answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-do-i-get-attention-for-one-of-my-own-questions-without-a-good-answer)

Answer (score 0):

You can use rectursive function for deep datas. Like this.
This function can also be used for deeper structures.

Further information about the recursive function here: [https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/recursive-functions/#:~:text=In%20programming%20terms%2C%20a%20recursive,can%20be%20solved%20quite%20easily](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/recursive-functions/#:%7E:text=In%20programming%20terms%2C%20a%20recursive,can%20be%20solved%20quite%20easily).

```js
const
  data = [
    {"key":9054,"title":"1","children":[
      {"key":8959,"title":"1-0","idFather":8959,"tableIsFamily":false,"children":[]},
      {"key":8943,"title":"1-1","idFather":8943,"tableIsFamily":false,"children":[]},
      {"key":9021,"title":"1-2","idFather":9021,"tableIsFamily":false,"children":[]},
      {"key":8969,"title":"1-3","idFather":8969,"tableIsFamily":false,"children":[]}]},
    {"key":9040,"title":"2","children":[
        {"key":8957,"title":"2-0","idFather":8957,"tableIsFamily":false,"children":[]},   
        {"key":8941,"title":"2-1","idFather":8941,"tableIsFamily":false,"children":[
          {"key":8947,"title":"2-1-0","idFather":8941},
          {"key":9855,"title":"2-1-1","idFather":8941}
        ]},
        {"key":8949,"title":"3-0","idFather":8949,"tableIsFamily":false,"children":[]},
        {"key":8983,"title":"3-1","idFather":8983,"tableIsFamily":false,"children":[]},
        {"key":10070,"title":"3-2","idFather":10070,"tableIsFamily":false,"children":[]}
      ]}
    ];
 const ids = [9054, 9021, 9040, 8941, 8947]
 
 filterData = (data)=> {
    const newData = data.filter((obj)=>ids.includes(obj.key));
    newData.forEach((obj)=>{obj.children ? obj.children = filterData(obj.children) : []});
    
    return newData;
 }
 
 console.log(filterData(data));
```